# Statistics from Google Analytics to e-shop

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Is it possible to get statistics from Google Analytics to e-shop administration? 
I would like to watch how many units of a product were sold or how often the product is displayed, etc. 
I followed this tutorial https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/hello-analytics-api but I don't know how to get specific information about the specific product.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the recently updated [Hello Analytics API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/) docs. And you can change the query to the core reporting API to use any of the [ecommerce dimensions and metrics](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=ecommerce) to request information.